# Decrypt Keychain with Password outside of Keychain-App

Tags: macos, software, keychain

so here is my problem:

we all know that the osx keychain is located in ~/Library/Keychains/something.keychain

now i've got this file and i know the master password for this keychain. is there a way to browse the keys in there using a external software or something? I don't want to import this keychain into my current one (if its possible).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by “external software”? Something that is not *Keychain Access*? Something from a third party (not Apple)? Something that can run on a platform other than Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following script to extract a password from the Keyring:

```
$ cat get_password_from_keyring 
#!/bin/bash
security find-generic-password -a $1 -g 2>&1 | grep password | cut -d \" -f 2
```

Comment: Nice tool. Here is the [manpage for *security(1)*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html).